# why it display the address of the string instead of the string

Tags: java, android

this is an android program I write for fun, but I am confused why the text view display the address of the string name instead of that string.
the program is pretty easy, take a string by edittext from user and set it as textview.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1,b2;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    CheckBox cb1,cb2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        cb1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new onclick());
        b2.setOnClickListener(new onclick());
    }

class onclick implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v==b1){
            String name=et1.getContext().toString();            /************mark********/

            tv1.setText(" "+name);
        }
        else if(v==b2){


    enter code here

            Intent myintent=new Intent();
            myintent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Other.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myintent);
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
String name = et1.getText().toString();
```

This will give the text entered by the user.

Comment: it works, thank you. what is the situation that the getContext() should  be used

Comment: getContext gives you the Context object associated with the view.  In this case the Activity itself.

Comment: @user3806772 getContext returns the context of the view (EditTex) is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity. I guess you are new to android development, so you can search online these things and read the documentation. All the best for developing apps. Do mark it as answer so that it can help other users as well :)

Comment: .toString() is unnecessary here.

Comment: @EJP getText() returns Editable (not String) and need to be converted to String to store it. Otherwise your IDE will definitely show error.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
   String name=et1.getContext().toString();
```

should be simply

```
   String name = et1.getText();
```

("Context" is different than "Text" and there is no reason for toString())